# If $T(a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})=aT(\mathbf{x})+bT(\mathbf{y})$, then $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to show that if $T$ is a linear transformation; that is if
$$T(a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})=aT(\mathbf{x})+bT(\mathbf{y})$$
for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$.

If I set $a=b=1$, and $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$, then I get
$$
T(\mathbf{0})=T(\mathbf{0})+T(\mathbf{0})\Rightarrow T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}
$$

Is this how I should show that $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: Yes. $ $$ $$ $$ $$ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly correct. Here are two of essentially the same (but admittedly less elegant ways) to see it:

Recall that $a \cdot \vec{ 0} =\vec{0}$.

Then, we know that $a \cdot T(\vec{0})=T(a \cdot \vec{0})=T(\vec{0})$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

Suppose that $a \vec{x}=\vec{x}$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$. What does this mean about $\vec{x}$?

Alternatively:
Suppose that $T(\vec{0})=\vec{a} \neq\vec{ 0}$. Then 
$$T(\vec{x})=T(\vec{x}+\vec{0})=T(\vec{x})+T(\vec{0}) \neq T(\vec{x}),$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are using the other definition of linear transformation but I have to use exactly $T(a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})=aT(\mathbf{x})+bT(\mathbf{y})$ definition or if I want to use your definition, I first have to prove that $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$ which I am again back in what I wanted to prove. Is my solution incorrect?

Comment: I am using the same definition. Can you demonstrate where I've deviated? Your solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see your edit when I wrote my comment.

Comment: No problem :). I'm interested to see where you see my use of a different definition.

Comment: I use the definition that $T(a\mathbf{x}+b\mathbf{y})=aT(\mathbf{x})+bT(\mathbf{y})$ but you are using the other one that $T(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y})=T(\mathbf{x})+T(\mathbf{y})$ and $T(\alpha\mathbf{x})=\alpha T(\mathbf{x})$. The two definitions are equivalent but if I want to use your solution I first have to prove that my definition implies yours and in doing that I already need $T(\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Tthese definitions are exactly the same. The former is only a more succinct way of stating it.

Comment: No problem. Here is a quick note on their equivalence. Suppose that $T(ax+by)=aT(x)+b(T(y)$. Then set $a,b=1$ and you obtain $T(x)+T(y)$. On the other hand, suppose that wlog $y=0$. Then $T(ax)=aT(x)$ as well. On the other hand, suppose that $T(ax)=aT(x)$ and $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$. Then $T(ax+by)=T(ax)+T(by)=aT(x)+bT(y).$

Comment: Yes, I know this that is why I said they are equivalent. If you put $y=0$, then you also need $T(0)=0$ (which is what I said in my previous comment). However, if instead you set $b=0$, then you do not need the result that $T(0)=0$. Thanks again for your help. I appreciate it.